# Получение аудио-стрима через Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Нужно получить аудио-стрим микрофона (не звука во вкладке, а именно микрофона) через расширение Chrome. Обычный `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })`, вызванный из фонового скрипта выкидывает исключение следующего содержания:

```
Uncaught (in promise) NavigatorUserMediaError {name: "MediaDeviceFailedDueToShutdown", message: "", constraintName: ""}
```

Гуглёж по проблеме ни к чему не привёл :(

Comment: Это не помогло? Вопрос похож https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310304/chrome-extension-microphone-capture

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев помогло, но не совсем это. Я не правильно понял тот ответ, думал что там предлагают держать открытое окно при записи микрофона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает, из-за того, что браузер не может спросить пользователя разрешение на получение звука, т.к. открытых окон нет.

Решение следующее: скриптом открыть окно внутри расширения (предварителньо создав его, вписав `getUserMedia`), единоразово разрешить доступ микрофону, закрыть окно и пользоваться расширением, т.к. у него уже будет разрешение для доступа к микрофону.